# Last uninstalled application

Tags: windows, windows-8, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Windows 7 uninstall log that shows who uninstalled what?](https://superuser.com/questions/297805/is-there-a-windows-7-uninstall-log-that-shows-who-uninstalled-what)

I accidenally uninstalled 1 of my applications. (Actually I wanted to uninstall another one) The problem is, I thought the uninstalled is the one that I wanted. But after uninstaller finished it's job and current applications'list refreshed, the application that I wanted to uninstall was still there. I checked the link on desktop: It was working too. Now, what I want to do is, to check what was last uninstalled application. Maybe there is some log file or something like that? Any suggestion? I'm using windows 8 x64 pro.

Comment: Have you checked the event logs?

Comment: I would check your restore points, by default, a restore point is created each time an application is uninstalled.

Comment: Huh? How did you not notice it was the wrong one during the un-installation process? I have never seen an un-installer that was plain/generic and did not indicate what program it is for (some even go so far as to make you fill out a web-form to explain why you are uninstalling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check under Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools --> Event Viewer. Expand the Windows Logs, and check under the Application log, as well as the other logs in there like the Setup and System logs. You might have to look at each entry in those logs to find the answer.