# Find out what uninstalled my application

Tags: windows, windows-10, event-log

I have an application, soundswitch, which I use on a daily basis (using keyboard shortcuts it switches sound device). Yesterday my keyboard shortcuts did not work, but I just thought something probably errored out, and all will be good after a restart.
Today it's still not working so I started investigating - it turns out the tool was uninstalled. There is only program files folder present, but it's empty. Registry has no information about it, and event viewer also knows nothing of it. I am the only user of this PC, and I need to know what has happened.

Is there any option to see uninstall/delete history on the machine? I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: What I have seen more than once is Windows 10 legitimately uninstalling non-compliant software.  See if (a) there is any evidence in Windows 10 Update History and (b) if there is a newer version for the software

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post can help you, I tried on Windows 10 and it worked.

[Is there a Windows 7 uninstall log that shows who uninstalled what?](https://superuser.com/questions/297805/is-there-a-windows-7-uninstall-log-that-shows-who-uninstalled-what)